# Returning a 403 from a custom model binder

Tags: c#, .net-core, api-design

We are using some custom model binders for our .Net Core api and have some logic in the model binder which should sometimes result in a `403` being returned by our api.

I am aware that you can use `Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBindingResult.Failed()` to return a `400` when model binding fails, however if it is due to fail as ar result of an attempt at `Unauthorized` access then we need to return a `403`, ideally with a custom message.

Comment: It's not recommended to set status codes or return results in the model binders as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding#recommendations-and-best-practices Can you check the parameter value directly in the action method and return Unauthorized if it's null or default?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to call `bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Unauthorized", "Reason")` within your `ModelBinder` implementation.

Then inside the controller you can use `if(ModelState.IsValid)` to assert if the ModelBinder worked correctly *and* if you had any validation errors in the process.

In your case you can then check if is is *not* valid and handle an unauthorised response in the controller as you normally would.

I would reserve `ModelBindingResult.Failed()` for catastrophic errors in model binding that are not intended (e.g. caused by malformed requests), as opposed to an intended behaviour that is desired by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Can´t you just return the status code?. You can attach your own message there.

```
return StatusCode(403);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this work as the model binding happens during the MVC pipeline and I returns a `Task` which, as far as I know, can't really be in the form of a `StatusCode`?

Comment: When you return a `Failed` it looks something like this:

`bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
return Task.FromResult(0);`

But `bindingContext` can only be set to `Failed` or `Success` and not to a specific reason for the failing :/

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately we decided to go with `ModelBindingResult.Failed()` and a custom error message that indicated that the failure was as a result of an authorisation failure.